# What is the order of returning integer array by getTimeCategories() in TimeAwareness In HMS

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

When I am using getTimeCategories() getting an integer array [6,8,1]. What does this imply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three element in the returning array in **getTimeCategories**() should in the given order
[ weekday(6) or weekend(7),
holiday(5) or not holiday(8),
period of day(morning(1) or afternoon(2) or evening(3) or night(4)) ]

They have the given respective values

[6/7,
5/8,
1/2/3/4]

So your value[6,8,1] means [weekday, not holiday, morning]